# How to import multiple csvs, assign variable and concatenate into one DataFrame with Pandas concat?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, performance, dataframe

I would like to optimize the code below. It works but I would like suggestions if it can be done more concisely and efficiently.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

files = glob.glob(os.path.join('data','*.csv'))

dfs = []

for file in files:

       variable = os.path.basename(file).split("_")[0] #split filename 
       df= pd.read_csv(file)
       df['variable'] = variable #assign variable
       dfs.append(df)

finalDf = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index = True)
```

Any ideas ? Thank you in advance

Pandas 0.21.1 and Python 3.6.5

Comment: It looks good to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of your code is perfectly fine. Concatenating a list of dataframes is more efficient than repeatedly appending to an existing dataframe.

#### Set dtype

What you can try and optimize is reading your csv file, i.e. `df = pd.read_csv(file)`. My only suggestion is to specify `dtype` parameter with a dictionary mapping column names to types. In particular, if you have columns with categorical data, map to `'category'` to ensure you optimize memory usage.

#### List comprehension + assign

You mention more concise code. You can utilize `pd.DataFrame.assign` to create a new series and set it to your filename. In addition, you can use a list comprehension:

```
dfs = [pd.read_csv(file).assign(variable=os.path.basename(file).split('_')[0]) \
       for file in glob.glob(os.path.join('data','*.csv'))]

finalDf = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

If you choose this method, you may lose readability, so document what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware assign  could be set like that as a chain and wrap all into a list comprehension . Also thanks for the dtype mapping parameter for optimisation.